# Regex to check ColdFusion code: Is tag name lowercase?

Tags: java, regex, coldfusion

I'm using Java to see if some ColdFusion code meets certain standards.

One of the things I want to check is if the tag name is all lowercase letters or numbers. The rest of the tag, like the attributes, can be any case.

`cfquery` is the tag name in this line: `<cfquery name="qryMyQuery">`. Because it is all lowercase, it should pass. But `<cfQuery>` should not pass.

Comment: Needs more details. I know regex, but not coldfusion, so can you add an example and the expected result?

Comment: @Laurel i will check the coldfusion code with regex.. u can help me with regex
For eg: coldfusion tags like <cfquery>  should be in smallcase

Comment: I understood that much. I can probably write something that checks for case. I meant you need to add more about what spacing should be.

Comment: I have rewritten your question to be specific (I hope it's what you meant). You can ask another question about indentation if need be.

Comment: @Laurel thanks for putting my question in a correct manner.
Solution doesnt seems to be working though.

Comment: @NewBie Check [this](http://trycf.com/gist/d2bf4a2204068658e388c0c3cf3e122b/acf2016?theme=monokai).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex will only match lowercase tag names: `</?[a-z0-9]+[\s>/]`. I am assuming that ColdFusion uses HTML/XML style syntax. It works on all types of tags: open, closed, and empty (but it's not a CFG parser, so embedded tags in `script`s may trip it).

As a Java String that's `"</?[a-z0-9]+[\\s>/]"`.

---

Edit: If it must match the entire tag, you can use: `</?[a-z0-9]+(?:>|[\s/][^>]*>)`

String: `"</?[a-z0-9]+(?:>|[\\s/][^>]*>)"`

This should work on a number of inputs. It passes for the first 2, and fails for the last 3 in this list:

```
<re STuff=caSeS></re ><NO><nO><N0T/>
```

This works at regex101.com.

Your Java code should look like:

```
 Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("</?[a-z0-9]+(?:>|[\\s/][^>]*>)");
    Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(
                   "<re STuff=caSeS></re ><NO><nO><N0T/>");

    while (regexMatcher.find()) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= regexMatcher.groupCount(); i++) {
            // matched text: regexMatcher.group(i)
            // match start: regexMatcher.start(i)
            // match end: regexMatcher.end(i)
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks @Laurel
What if tag has the attributes, i just want to check bold part mentioned in my question.

Comment: @NewBie Attributes come after the tag name, (the bolded part in your q). My regex doesn't touch those.

Comment: It didnt worked when i tried whole tag with attributes as mentioned in Q.
It worked when i passed "<cfquery>"

Comment: if i put a space after tag name "<cfquery >"in that case also its not working.

Comment: @NewBie I've added some Java code, so it should definitely work.